# How to run a class function

Tags: python, class, instance

I was trying to write some code that would take in the number of sides of a polygon and a user can just randomly input the length of each side

I wanted to make a separate class polygon and the following was my code:

```
#numSides=int(input(Number of sides))
class polygon(object):
    def __init__(self,x):                                       #useless code
        self.x=x                                                            #useless code
        self.x=[]                                                           #useless code
    def __inputSides__(self):
        #counter=0
        #for i in range(x):
        #   counter=counter+1

        numSides=int(input("number of sides"))
        list_=[]
        for i in range(numSides):
            length=float(input("length"))
            list_.append(length)
        return list_

    def __dispSides__(self,list_):
        for i in list_:
            print("side length",i)

stone= polygon()
stone.__dispSides__(4)
```

but then in the second to last line i was getting an error that said :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I was wondering how can i fix this and why I am getting this error?

thanks!

Comment: The error message is straightforward: you defined your `polygon` class to require an argument, but you didn't provide one.

Comment: You need an argument to `polygon()` for the `x` parameter in `__init__(self, x)`.

Comment: It's not clear why you need that parameter, since after you use it you overwrite it with `self.x = []`.

Comment: You never use `self.x` anywhere else in the class, what's the point of it? Maybe that's why you have the comments `#useless code`. Why do you add useless code to your program?

Comment: Why have you named all the other methods with double underscores? You shouldn't use that for your own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper class wouldn't prompt the user for the side lengths; the code that *creates* a `Polygon` should be responsible for the I/O and simply pass the values as arguments to `Polygon.__init__`.

```
class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def display_sides(self):
        for s in self.sides:
            print("side length", s)


numSides = int(input("number of sides"))
sides = []
for i in range(numSides):
    length = float(input("length"))
    sides.append(length)

s = Polygon(sides)
s.display_sides()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite straight-forward question.

Whenever you call your polygon class its `__init__` function is run automatically. You've set this initiation function to require 2 arguments: `self` & `x`. Whenever you initiate your class you will thus have to provide your class with an `x` argument.

Meaning instead of declaring `stone = polygon()`, you should declare something like `stone = polygon(x)`.

Furthermore, your reason for passing and initiating the `x` argument is unclear since no matter what value `x` is given, it is never passed along to any method within your class. This is because after declaring `self.x = x`, it is immediately overwritten to be an empty list by your `self.x=[]` declaration (leaving the actual `x`-argument unused).

Answer (score 0):

In same code, I applied two fixes.Hope you wanted the same result.

```
class polygon(object):

def __init__(self,x=[]):                                       #useless code
    self.x=x       
# force user to input numSide and length
numSides=int(input("number of sides"))
list_=[]
for i in range(numSides):
    length=float(input("length"))
    list_.append(length)

#finally list_ argument is a declaration so you have to define it(assign value)
def __dispSides__(self,list_=list_):
    for i in list_:
        print("side length",i)



stone= polygon()
stone.__dispSides__()
```

fix 1: `__init__(self,x=[]):` define x with declaration to set a default value

fix 2: 
`def __dispSides__(self,list_=list_):`
here you declared a variabe **list_** but actually you wanted to pass previous `list_` value here(as it seems ) so do pass it a value.

Avoid Error: `stone.__dispSides__(4)`# passing a non-iterable will raise an error